# Changing URL of Woocomerce order-received Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, payment-gateway

To add event in Facebook Pixel I need to add the link of the page.

But after paying, the url is not fixed as in the picture below.

If you're asking what it has to do with Facebook Pixel, When the url is fixed, I will be able to see how much money I have earned from the customer on Facebook Pixel.

Example:

[image]

[image]

I want URL like this:

[image]

I searched everywhere this topic but i couldn't find. They were just about editing thank you page

Comment: So you are looking to take the query string out of the URL when viewing orders? Can't you just add the URL with the query string into Facebook Pixel and have it be a unique event? Or maybe Facebook Pixel can just track a URL that contains `order-received` or whichever link you are tracking.

Comment: What I want to do is make the url part uniform. example.com/checkout/order-received like this. I can't add this to the pixel as the url changes with each order. I hope I was able to explain. If you have any other suggestions, I'll listen

Comment: `example.com/checkout/order-received` It will give only thank you message not order details after payment if want to modify the URL till `order-received`

Comment: Let me make the question shorter. I want the total value of the customer's last purchase to be written on the order-received page. So that I can see how much money the ad made me. Sorry, I hope I explained better.